# How to compile pygtk from source for python2.6 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, compilation, makefile, pygtk

I have a application which is stuck at python2.6. I cannot port it to python2.7 due to specific and complicated extensions.

The probleme is that 12.04 removes pygtk for python2.6 as python2.7 becomes the default python version.

I need then to build pygtk for python2.6 from source. I have followed the readme but I am doing something wrong. (the doc is quite succinct)

The build looks ok, as I can import gtk if I am in the decompressed archive folder (I do a *python -c 'import gtk'*).
But the make install doesn't work properly.

AFAICT, I have export'ed PYTHON & PYTHONPATH variables to the proper path.

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6
```

Any idea on what's wrong with this config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm getting farther than you are, but here's what I'm doing so far. Maybe we can figure this out together.

```
$ sudo su
# pip install pygtk
```

This generates a bunch of errors, including "To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file." After reading that and other things, I tried this:

```
# cd build/pygtk
# chmod 755 configure
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

This finds the right version of Python, but now can't find GLIB. Errors include, "This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed." When I look in `config.log` I find this error, "fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory". I found [a help page](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Could_not_run_GLIB_test_program,_checking_why) that suggested you might get this error if you haven't installed a development version of GLIB.

```
# apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Progress! I now see a new error, "No package 'pygobject-2.0' found". That error appears in [a forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1837389) with a suggestion to install `python-gobject-dev`.

```
# apt-get install python-gobject-dev
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

No errors, so I try running `make` and `make install`. The first one works, but the install fails with an error, "/bin/bash: line 16: ../py-compile: Permission denied". Permission denied is weird when running as root. After flailing for a while, I go back to the output of the configure script and see a message, "checking for PYCAIRO... no", followed by another, "not checking for gtk due to missing pycairo". A little guesswork leads me to install another module.

```
# apt-get install python-cairo-dev
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

That solves the pycairo complaint, but there are a bunch more, including GTK.

```
# apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

That solved most of the complaints, just LIBGLADE is missing.

```
# apt-get install libglade2-dev
# PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6 ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

OK, all the modules will be built, but it says, "Numpy support: no".

```
# make
# make install
```

This fails with the same error I saw earlier, "/bin/bash: line 16: ../py-compile: Permission denied".

I'm going to leave it here for now and come back to it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use easy_install for 2.6, suppose in your ubuntu you have 2.6 and 2.7 installed. you can have easy_install (by default for 2.7), and easy_install-2.6 to install the dedicated packages for 2.6.